# Discrete Mathematics - Modular Arithmetic Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm currently studying Discrete Mathematics at Uni and I have run into a question I cannot solve.

Define sets $S, T$ and $E$ as follows:

$S = \{n \in \Bbb Z \mid n \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \}$

$T = \{n \in \Bbb Z \mid n \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \}$

$E = \{n \in \Bbb Z \mid n \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \}$.

Prove that $S \times T \subset E \times E$.

I've tried to define each domain individually using the quotient remainder theorem to get the statements

$S \times T = \{4q , 4q+2 \mid 4q \in S , 4q + 2 \in T \}$

$E \times E = \{2q , 2q \mid 2q \in E \}$

And since I believe you ignore repetition,

$\vert S \times T \vert = 2$

$\vert E \times E \vert = 1$

But that means $\vert S \times T \vert$ is not a proper subset of $\vert E \times E \vert$?

Could someone lemme know where I went wrong or if I've gone about it completely wrong.

Cheers.

Comment: Note for next time: please mention what you tried to do and where you get stuck. The more specific, the better!

Comment: $S$ is the set of all multiples of 4. There are infinitely many of them, so $|S|=\infty$. Thus $|S\times T|=\infty$, not $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what do these sets look like?

$S\times T = \{(n,m)\in\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}\mid n\equiv 0\pmod{4}, m\equiv 2\pmod{4}\}$.

Intuitively, if $n\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, then it's a multiple of $4$, so certainly it is a multiple of $2$ (it is equivalent to $0\pmod{2})$.

Likewise, if $m\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, it is $2$ more than a multiple of $4$, so surely it is divisible by $2$ also.

(You can prove both of these results "non-intuitively" using the definition of $\text{mod}$, if you like.)

But $E\times E$ is the set of *all* $2$-tuples of even numbers, so whatever is in $S\times T$ should be in $E\times E$. An example of the fact that the containment is strict is that $(0,0)$ is in $E\times E$ but not in $S\times T$.

Comment: I didn't think of it like that, CHEERS MATE THANK YOU!